# How do I get a red status light?

Tags: prison-architect

How do I make a status light turn red? I'm able to make it turn green by hooking it up to a power switch. My assumption is that by sending the signal through a NOT logic gate first that the status light would turn red, but instead it just turns off.

Comment: That is a binary signal and its either Green == 1 or NotGreen == 0, why would you expect a third red one?

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Because in the mouse-over description of the status light it says it can go green and red. I've also seen it on at least one video, but I dont remember which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, **not possible**, it's the bug [0008882: No red lights for status lights](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=8882)

Answer (score 3):

According to [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/233450/discussions/0/620696522168801209/) and the [wiki](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Status_light) the status light will only light up green; it is impossible to make it go red. This will probably be changed in the next build, which is why the description says it can be both green and red. This is further supported by [this source](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/prison-architect-alpha-24-features-confidential-informants-and-improved-modding-systems-378671) and also [this one](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=49864&start=0). All of these sources mention that there is a status light, but none mention that it can be red. Considering that the last source is an official Introversion update, you are unable to make the status light go red.

Comment: You mention you think it will happen next build, but what makes you say that? The sources you linked to are from 10 alphas ago and over a year.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Pure speculation on my part. If not in the next build, then in a few builds from now. The point is, since red is in the description, it will be changed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The status light can only go green and unlit, this is stated in detail on the Devwiki in this post here:

http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Status_Light